# Using an object's string variable in a switch statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
    switch (token.type.GetName()) 
    {
        case PascalTokenType.BEGIN.name: // ERROR: A CONSTANT VALUE IS EXPECTED
        {
            CompoundStatementParser compoundParser = new CompoundStatementParser(this);
            statementNode = compoundParser.parse(token);
            break;
        }
    }
```

`GetName()` and `name` both return strings. This is what the object looks like:

```
    public static readonly PascalTokenType BEGIN = new PascalTokenType("BEGIN");
```

I know I could get around this problem by changing it to an `if` statement but when this is complete I'm going to have at least 20 conditions so I'd rather not. I'm supposing it's because `BEGIN.name` isn't assigned until runtime?

Comment: If you know the conditions ahead of time (big assumption on my part), why not create an enum for it and compare based on that?

Comment: So pass an enum to the `PascalTokenType` constructor instead of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you have the right idea. The problem is that this value could change at runtime, which the compiler doesn't like.

Comment: Once `BEGIN` is created it will never change. Is there a way to create an immutable object with immutable members that the compiler will accept in a switch condition?

Comment: It's not enough that you know it won't change. It's that the compiler doesn't know it won't change. There are probably some workarounds, but I find that when I am trying to fit a square peg in a round hole, I am usually approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: Instead of `PascalTokenType.BEGIN.name` I'm just going to type `"BEGIN"`. Seems to be the most straightforward way to do it without having to rewrite it as `if-else`.